# initialize castle container from a stream (not file)

Tags: castle-windsor

Is it possible to initialize a castle container (windsor) by passing a stream to 
the XmlInterpreter somehow? It appears that the current implementation only supports
files.
thanx,
-tzurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from [AbstractStreamResource](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/Core/trunk/src/Castle.Core/Resource/AbstractStreamResource.cs), then you can do:

```
var c = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new MyStreamResource(...)));
```

See [FileResource](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/Core/trunk/src/Castle.Core/Resource/FileResource.cs) for guidance.